MSB3030: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features.resources.dll - it was not found
After the latest update of visual studio 2022 I got several problems. The first one, I couldn't install new nuget package, now different application is throwing error.
File: Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.tragets: Line 5034

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  MSB3030 Could not copy the file "C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\microsoft.codeanalysis.features\4.0.0\lib\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features.dll" because it was not found.   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  5034    

5034 line code:
<Copy
    SourceFiles="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)"
    DestinationFiles="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'$(OutDir)%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
    SkipUnchangedFiles="$(SkipCopyUnchangedFiles)"
    OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"
    Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
    RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"
    UseHardlinksIfPossible="$(CreateHardLinksForCopyLocalIfPossible)"
    UseSymboliclinksIfPossible="$(CreateSymbolicLinksForCopyLocalIfPossible)"
    Condition="'$(UseCommonOutputDirectory)' != 'true'"
        >

  <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWritesShareable"/>
  <Output TaskParameter="CopiedFiles" ItemName="ReferencesCopiedInThisBuild"/>
  <Output TaskParameter="WroteAtLeastOneFile" PropertyName="WroteAtLeastOneFile"/>

</Copy>

what could be the problem?
